# HasOne with OneToMany mapping relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Country> VisitedCountries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; 
   public Owner Owner { get; set; }       
}
```

I map this relationship as

```
public class CarConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder)
   {
       builder.ToTable("Car");
       builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
       builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
       builder.HasOne(x => x.Owner);
   }
}
```

As for now, I added OwnerConfiguration file as a separate configuration file

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Owner> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Owner");
     builder.HasMany(x => x.VisitedCountries);
     ...
}
```

> My question is: How can I refactor this and use only on map
>   configuration file (CarConfiguration for example) and delete
>   OwnerConfiguration file?

Comment: You can configure all your entities in the DbContex's OnConfiguring override.

Answer (score 1):

For `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, it allows configuration for an entity type to be factored into a separate class, and you could not use it for different model.

In general, there are two ways to configure the model, `IEntityTypeConfiguration` in separted file and configuring in `OnModelCreating` directly.

Where there are many models, it is recommended to use `IEntityTypeConfiguration` for eparate configurations which is easy to configure. If you just want to avoid configure `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CarConfiguration());`, you could try like `modelBuilder.ApplyEntityTypeConfigurations(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`.

If you want to have one place to configure, you could follow `OnModelCreating` like

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<Car>(c =>
            {
            c.ToTable("Car");
            c.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            c.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            c.HasOne(x => x.Owner);
            });
    }
```